# Pair elements equally between two ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a school assignment that goes like this:
Write a method that takes the lists of students and graders
as arguments and returns a single ArrayList where each element has the format "studentName, graderName".
The students should be split as evenly as possible among the graders. For example, you may assign 7 students to one grader and 6 to another, but not 8 students to one grader and 5 to another.

This is what I have for now.

```
    public static ArrayList<String> assignGraders(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<String> graders) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int average = students.size()/graders.size();
    int j = 0; //Index of grader list
    for(int i = 0; i<students.size(); i++) {
        list.add(students.get(i) + ", " + graders.get(j));
        if((i % average == 0) && (i!= 0) && (j<graders.size()-1)){
            j++;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add an actual question to your question.

Comment: yea sorry, the question is what is wrong with my code? It does not pair them equally. I get one grader with 11 students, one with 10 students, and the rest with 9 students....

Comment: You're not consistently incrementing j. This should be a simple round-robin problem : loop through your students, assign each student to the next grader. If you hit the last grader before exhausting the student list, reset the grader index back to 0

Comment: Well, I think you are making all this way to complicated. Instead of calculating an average just cycle through your graders: Assign first student to grader1, second to grader2 etc pp ....until you reach the end and start again with grader1

Comment: also  here int average = students.size()/graders.size(); are you sure this division will result in a smooth integer?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it:

```
public static ArrayList<String> assignGraders(List<String> students, List<String> graders) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int average = students.size()/graders.size();
        int j = 0; //Index of grader list
        for(int i = 0; i<students.size(); i++) {
            list.add(students.get(i) + ", " + graders.get(j));
            j++;
            if (j == graders.size()) {
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to cycle through the list of students, assuming you have 8 students and three teachers

```
First student --> first teacher
Second student --> Second teacher
Third student --> Third teacher
Fourth student --> first teacher
Fifth student --> Second teacher
Sixth student --> Third teacher
Seventh student --> first teacher
Eight Student --> Second Teacher
```

Start learning to Implement to an Interface, rather implement to an implementation.
Here List would be the interface and ArrayList would be your implementation.
That way you api is more adaptable

```
public static ArrayList<String> assignGraders(ArrayList<String> students, ArrayList<String> graders)
    {
        int studentsSize = students.size();
        int gradersSize = graders.size();

        int studentToGrader = studentsSize / gradersSize;
        int assignedStudents = 0;

        ArrayList<String> studToGrader = new ArrayList<String>(students.size());
        while(assignedStudents < studentsSize)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while(i < studentToGrader)
            {
                studToGrader.add(students.get(assignedStudents) + "--" + graders.get(i));
                assignedStudents++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return studToGrader;
    }
```